# how to find the most recently checked in file in VSS

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I have to figure out the most recently checked in files on VSS. I know the date of check in but not much info other than the directory to which they were checked. There are a large number of files and I was wondering if there is a report I can pull out from some where.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right-click on the directory in VSS Explorer and choose View History: you can add date filters to the search, then output the results as text.

Comment: The most recently checked in files will be on top. Just add a recent from date to filter if you have huge amounts of files.

Comment: Works. Thanks for the quick response.